# Avoiding duplicate jobs when using Sidekiq's `unique_for` and `Sidekiq::Limiter.concurrent` in the same worker

Tags: sidekiq

## Summary

I am struggling to deduplicate Sidekiq jobs and limit concurrency in the same worker without introducing a race condition that causes the worker to miss updates. Below are the solutions I have tried and the reason why they do not satisfy me. Can you suggest an improvement to my solutions or another way to solve this problem?

## Solution 1: use `unique_until: :start` with `Sidekiq::Limiter.concurrent`

Currently, the worker uses `unique_until: :start` and a `Sidekiq::Limiter.concurrent` lock.

The downside of this solution is that The interaction between these two Sidekiq features causes many duplicate jobs in the queue. Here is a sequence of events that cause duplicate jobs:

1. `Worker.perform_async(1)` enqueues job A1
2. Job A1 starts, releases its unique lock, and gets the concurrent lock
3. `Worker.perform_async(2)` enqueues job B1
4. Job B1 starts, releases its unique lock, fails to get the concurrent lock, and reschedules itself. There is now no lock for `Worker` with argument 2.
5. `Worker.perform_async(2)` enqueues job B2.  I would like this to be a no-op, but it enqueues another job because we released the unique lock in step 4.
6. `Worker.perform_async(2)` enqueues job B3... and so on.

## Solution 2: use `unique_until: :success` with `Sidekiq::Limiter.concurrent`

I can fix the duplicate jobs issue if I switch to `unique_until: :success` (the default behavior if `unique_until` is not specified).

The downside of this solution is that it opens up a race condition where the worker misses updates that happen while a job is running.

## Solution 3: replace the limiter with a dedicated Sidekiq process

I can fix the duplicate jobs issue and avoid the race condition if I stop using `Sidekiq::Limiter.concurrent` and instead use a queue that is handled by a Sidekiq process that only has one thread.

The downside of this solution is that I have to use sadly resource-constrained hardware, so adding a second Sidekiq process is impactful.

## Code example for solution 1

This shows how I am using the uniqueness & limiter features:

```rb
class ExpensiveWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options unique_for: 30.minutes, unique_until: :start

  EXPENSIVE_JOB_LIMITER = Sidekiq::Limiter.concurrent('expensive_job',
                                                      1,
                                                      wait_timeout: 5.seconds,
                                                      lock_timeout: 15.minutes)

  def perform(id)
    EXPENSIVE_JOB_LIMITER.within_limit do
      Rails.logger.info "Processing #{id}..."
      sleep 10
    end
  end
end
```

## Details about what I am trying to solve

For the sake of simplicity, I am going to describe the data we are working with as author models that each have many books.  We have `RebuildAuthorImagesWorker` and `ClassifyAuthorGenreWorker` that both take an author ID as their only argument.

Both of these workers perform CPU & RAM-intensive calculations on an author and on the author's books. We use `Sidekiq::Limiter.concurrent` to ensure that only one of these workers has an active job at any given time. We do this to avoid impacting our puny servers. (We also have many other workers who do not need to be limited in this way.)

It is common for many updates to happen on the same author or on that author's books during a short period of time, because of multiple active users or because one user updated multiple books by the same author. We use `unique_for: :start` to prevent `RebuildAuthorImagesWorker` from being enqueued multiple times for the same author.  Ditto for `ClassifyAuthorGenreWorker`.  We want to avoid the duplicate jobs because of the system overhead associated with running them. The jobs are idempotent, so duplicate jobs do not cause data issues. (It is OK and normal for one job of each worker to be enqueued for the same author.)

If `RebuildAuthorImagesWorker` is actively running on author A, and then user X makes an update to author A before the `RebuildAuthorImagesWorker` job finishes, then we *do* want to enqueue a second `RebuildAuthorImagesWorker` job for author A, so we do not miss incorporating data from the user X's update in the image. That is why we use `unique_until: :start`.

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us what you are trying to achieve so we can give you alternative suggestions for implementation.

Comment: I just added a "Details about what I am trying to solve" section. Does that give you the info you are asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea:

When the user wants to change Author A, I would enqueue a scheduled, unique `UpdateAuthorJob` for Author A which updates their info **10 minutes from now**. That way, the user can make lots of changes to the author and the system will wait for that 10 minute cooldown period before performing the actual update work, ensuring that you get all the updates as one group.

Comment: This would not eliminate duplicate jobs, but it should dramatically reduce them at the cost of increased latency.  It seems likely to be a net win for my use case.  Thanks!